# Why I can't see "thin" option in VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone?

Tags: virtual-machine, vcenter, vmware-converter

The help and many web pages shows me screenshots of VM conversion process.
But I can't see disk resize options when run it.
VM's power is down. No snapshots.
VM compat is Workstation 9.0 virtual machine.
Disk now contains 40G allocated + 40G unallocated space. I want to shrink it down to 40G